# IUserRequestBuilder does not contain a definition for FindRooms, HOw to solve it in C#.net using microsoft graph?

Tags: c#, .net, botframework, microsoft-graph-api

I want list name of rooms created.  I got an error at `FindingRooms` method, `IUserRequestBuilder`  does not contain a definition for  `FindRooms`. How to solve it?

```
 IPublicClientApplication publicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create("****-8d12-45ce-99dc-ee97478abc48")
            .WithTenantId("****-0c15-41f2-9858-b64924a83a6c").WithRedirectUri("http://localhost")
            .Build();

             var password = new SecureString();

            password.AppendChar('<');
            password.AppendChar('T');
            password.AppendChar('N');
            password.AppendChar('>');
            password.AppendChar('7');
 UsernamePasswordProvider authProvider = new UsernamePasswordProvider(publicClientApplication, scopes);
            GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
            Microsoft.Graph.User me = graphClient.Me.Request()
                .WithUsernamePassword("Tej@indica.onmicrosoft.com", password)
                .GetAsync().Result;

            var findRooms = await  graphClient.Me


         .FindRooms("Test@indica.onmicrosoft.com")
            .Request()
               .GetAsync();
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to get a conference room in c#.net?

Comment: Check my answer. I got a success by add `Microsoft.Graph.Beta` package. If it helps, please mark it as answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, the [`findRooms`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-findrooms?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) API is in Graph beta version. So, you need to add `Microsoft.Graph.Beta` package.

[image]